# Scala IDE (Eclipse) Run as Scala Application

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I'm relatively new to the scala language (and programming in general). I recently installed the JDK and the Scala IDE (for eclipse). The setup went smoothly, but I encountered an issue upon trying to run a Hello World application. When I attempt to "Run As" the only available options are "Java Applet" and "Java Application". How do I proceed in trying to run as a "Scala Application"? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

1. Right click on the scala object having main method
2. Choose `Run As` -> `Run Configurations`
3. Double click on `Scala Application` from `Run Configurations` window
4. Type the Object Name in the `Main Class`: (for eg: if HelloWorld.scala is the object having main method, give it as HelloWorld)

Comment: And should I "type the Object Name" for every single project? Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have done all of the following steps:

1. Switch to the Scala perspective
2. Make sure the project is registered as a Scala project, not a Java project or any other kind of project. When you create the project, you can do this with `New -> Scala project`. If you have *already* created or imported the project, you can right-click on the project's root directory, then choose Scala and then Add Scala Nature. Alternatively, if it's an `sbt` project, you can use the sbt-eclipse plugin for sbt to generate an Eclipse project configuration for your existing project, and then reload the project in Eclipse.
3. Create an appropriate main object with a main method, if you don't already have one.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but how might I go about creating an appropriate main object with a main method?

Comment: In my case the problem was that I copied some files (notably Main.scala) from one my previous projects and forgot to rewrite the "package ..." part of the program.

Comment: @FilipB.Vondrášek It was the exact same problem for me as well!

Answer (score 3):

Try to click right button on the Scala object with `main` method (not on the root project element). Then the "Run as... Scala application" menu item appears.

Answer (score 0):

I did make the main class in Java and simple call previously renamed "main in Scala". 
After this both @Run As@ and @Export@ works fine